# Using Nem-library or nem-sdk on nativescript angular app

Tags: nativescript, blockchain, nem

I would like to integrate the nem-blockchain sdk or library into my mobile app.

```
https://github.com/NEMPH/nem-apps-lib
https://nemlibrary.com/
https://github.com/QuantumMechanics/NEM-sdk
```

any working solution is welcomed

Comment: It shouldn't be difficult. You can follow this: https://docs.nativescript.org/core-concepts/accessing-native-apis-with-javascript

Comment: I tried but it is not leading me anywhere